# Presence Update event spams

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I used presence update for my Discord bot so when me or my friends are getting live on Twitch, the bot would send a message in a channel and console log. But when we go live, the bot does the job, like, it sends the first message then it starts spamming. As you may expect, I don't have the knowledge in js as I am a beginner. So, can someone tell me how to fix this problem or if it can be fixed? Here is my code:

```
    if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
    newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
        };
    });
});
```

And here is the console.log spam:

```
Mini-Game#8953 is streaming at https://www.twitch.tv/murus.
Mini-Game#8953 is streaming at https://www.twitch.tv/murus.
Mini-Game#8953 is streaming at https://www.twitch.tv/murus.
Mini-Game#8953 is streaming at https://www.twitch.tv/murus.
```

Comment: I added `break;` but it gave me `Illegal use of break statement.` so I used `return;` and now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: i will move that to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `return` after the `console.log()` inside the `forEach`

```
newPresence.activities.forEach((activity,idx,arr) => {
        if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
            return; //---> ADD this
        };
    });
```